# Qt Designer Showing Black Calendar Widget

Tags: css, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, designer

I'm trying to build an app using Qt Designer for Python, but I'm having a problem where the Calendar appears to be in black color making all the days invisible!

[image: PyQt5 Designer Calendar]

The Calendar is new, I'm simply dragging then dropping it on the Main Window, there's nothing in the styleSheet for the calendar, but I did change the background color for the Main Window by using this styleSheet:

```
background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(45, 67, 241, 0.8), stop:1 rgba(172, 247, 255, 0.8));
border-radius:10px;
```

Removing the styleSheet for the Main Window solves the problem, but I need it as the background colors are required.

Here's the Python code if needed:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
  def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(45, 67, 241, 0.8), stop:1 rgba(172, 247, 255, 0.8));border-radius:10px;")
    MainWindow.showMaximized()
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.wFHWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.wFHWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 570, 471, 571))
    self.wFHWidget.setObjectName("wFHWidget")
    self.calendarWidget = QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget(self.wFHWidget)
    self.calendarWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 40, 264, 183))
    self.calendarWidget.setObjectName("calendarWidget")
```

The Widget which the calendar is part of (wFHWidget) also has some styleSheet, but when I removed it, the calendar remained in black so I assumed it's not the cause for the issue. Also, removing the styleSheet from the Main Window while keeping the styleSheet in the wFHWidget returns the calendar to its default view (not black) which is another confirmation that the issue is only with the Main Window styleSheet.

Here's what the Main Window, Widget & Calendar look like at the end:

[image: App Screenshot]

Here's a short video of the process in case it's needed for further showing the issue:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/VZetLUv2WKV8ck46A

*sorry for the video's low quality, using work's PC and I don't have a screen recorder installed.*

Comment: Style sheets are *cascading*: they propagate to child objects. When dealing with complex widgets (such as QCalendarWidget) if you set a property, you must set *all* properties. Use proper [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types).

Comment: @musicamante if I understood correctly (I hope), I'm applying the styleSheet to the entire window which in turn is applying the CSS code to the child objects of that window, so I updated the styleSheet to: ```QMainWindow#MainWindow{background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0, x2:0, y2:1, stop:0 rgba(45, 67, 241, 0.8), stop:1 rgba(172, 247, 255, 0.8));border-radius:10px;}``` but this just removed the background color from the Main Window!

Comment: `MainWindow` is the container. The actual widget is `centralWidget`. Note that you should *never* use fixed geometries, and alwaya use [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) instead.

Comment: @musicamante that was perfect, thank you so much. One question tho, is it possible to keep thing as there are, but just make it so that the centralWidget's CSS ignores the QCalendarWidget? As in apply the CSS to all the child objects except QCalendarWidget. As for you advice, I was going to use the layouts, but just wanted to make this as a prototype to the coworker who requested it first, thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately (as far as I know of), due to the nature of QSS (and the original implementation they are based on, which is CSS 2.1), there is no way to set *exceptions* for properties. And I would discourage so in any way: except for some very basic widgets, most widgets are *complex* and, as said above, they require that if even a single property is set, all other properties must be set too. I would suggest to create a rule for the background with a list of widget *classes* you want it applied to.